# Make VoiceOver announce text pre-10.9

Tags: macos, cocoa, voiceover

I want VoiceOver to speak some text in an NSTextView that it won't say spontaneously, basically text added programmatically while the view has focus. OS X 10.9 added the NSAccessibilityAnnouncementRequestedNotification API as a way to do this (although it for some reason says macOS 10.7+ on the [Apple documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsaccessibilityannouncementrequestednotification?language=objc)), but I want my app to work on 10.7 as well.

EDIT: I made the code using NSAccessibilityAnnouncementRequestedNotification compile and run on 10.7 ([by adding a number of missing definitions](https://github.com/angstsmurf/spatterlight/blob/9221688833ae2046305eccbe9e313b673ba05e53/application/GlkTextBufferWindow.m#L15-L28)), but it seems to have no effect prior to 10.9.

I think I've worked out a way to trick VoiceOver into thinking that the text I want it to speak is selected, (basically returning the string and the range I want to be read when asked for the NSAccessibilityAttributedStringForRangeParameterizedAttribute or NSAccessibilitySelectedTextRangeAttribute) and then post a NSAccessibilityValueChangedNotification. This pretty much works, but [makes VoiceOver say "Selection Replaced"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53689109/suppress-voiceover-saying-selection-replaced) whenever the user starts typing anything in the text view, on any OS newer than 10.7.

So, my question is: Is there a better way to do what I want?

Comment: When the documentation say `macOS 10.7+` that means that it's available from 10.7 and above. Compare this to symbols that have been deprecated and are no longer available which would be written as for example "macOS 10.0–10.14"

Comment: Sometimes new API is added with support going back to previous versions of the OS as well.

Comment: Yeah, I made the code using NSAccessibilityAnnouncementRequestedNotification compile and run on 10.7 (had to add [a number of missing definitions](https://github.com/angstsmurf/spatterlight/blob/9221688833ae2046305eccbe9e313b673ba05e53/application/GlkTextBufferWindow.m#L15-L28)), but it seems to have no effect prior to 10.9. At least not in this use case.